# Azure Batch - No files on node after task completion

Tags: azure, azure-batch

I'm using Azure Batch .NET API. After tasks completion, I try to retrieve the output files (or any files) from the tasks via `CloudTask.GetNodeFile()` but this throws a "not found" exception. Same for **stdout** `t.GetNodeFile(Microsoft.Azure.Batch.Constants.StandardOutFileName)` and **stderr** `t.GetNodeFile(Microsoft.Azure.Batch.Constants.StandardErrorFileName)`. There is simply no files of any sort on the node (verified via Azure portal). Job and pool are not yet deleted when I do the check and nodes are in "Idle" state.

Here is a relevant snippet of code, note that this is basically one of the examples from the [official azure-batch-samples at github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-batch-samples/tree/master/CSharp):

```cs
IPagedEnumerable<CloudTask> ourTasks = job.ListTasks(new ODATADetailLevel(selectClause: "id,state,url"));
client.Utilities.CreateTaskStateMonitor().WaitAll(ourTasks, TaskState.Completed, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(config.TimeoutMinutes));
Console.WriteLine("Tasks are done.");

foreach (CloudTask t in ourTasks)
{
     t.ListNodeFiles(recursive: true).ToList(); // always of size 1, with only element being "/wd"
}
```

Comment: When you verified on the Azure Portal that there were no files, do you have more than one node in your pool? If you retrieve the executed task (either via GetTask or .Refresh()) and then look at the ExecutionInformation property, did the task start and complete successfully? Is the SchedulingErrors property populated?

Comment: @fpark Yes, I do have more than one node in my pool. Can this be the reason? I wasn't even aware of the `ExecutionInformation` property, will take a look.

Comment: When verifying if a node has any files on it for the task, you will need to find the correct compute node it ran on (this can be found on the `ComputeNodeInformation` property of `CloudTask`). If you use `GetNodeFile()` on a `CloudTask` object, then the Batch Service will automatically find which node the task ran on and return the file contents. You should check `ExecutionInformation` and if `SchedulingError` is populated.

Comment: @fpark So...more than one node in the pool isn't the problem.

Comment: Most likely not, if you are using `CloudTask.GetNodeFile()`. Were you able to check the `ExecutionInformation` and `SchedulingError` properties?